# How to assign value of a fragment class variable from another fragment class and access that variable in activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using tab layout and want to update the value of  a variable of 1st tab from 2nd and 3rd tab.

is it possible to do what i asked about .
i have searched many things but couldn't get accurate or convincing answer.
please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: use custom listener interface

Comment: can you show me

Comment: ok, use same approach as my answer but instead of activity , implement listener in 1st fragment